# JavaScript - Using return argument of function that has AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following function in javascript:

```js
function checkFunc(msg) {
  $.getJSON("myurl.php", {
    dtccode: msg
  }, function(j) {
    return j.boolField;
  }); //JSON call
}
```

And I call it in another function:

```js
function check(msg) {
  var ret = checkFunc1(); //some other function
  ret = checkFunc2() && ret; //some other function
  ret = checkFunc3() && ret; //some other function
  ret = checkFunc() && ret;
  if (ret) {
    //code
  }
}
```

My problem is, that I know the checkFunc should return false, but it returns true. I think this may be a synchronization issue, but I don't know what to do.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous. Means that you have to use callback function to get the result. Like so:

```
function checkFunc(msg, callback) {
  $.getJSON("myurl.php", {
    dtccode: msg
  }, function(j) {
    callback(j.boolField);
  }); //JSON call
}
```

and

```
function check(msg) {
  checkFunc(msg, function(result){
     alert(result);
  }); 
}
```

EDIT: Using deferred system:

```
$.getJSON("myurl.php").done(function(j) {
    callback(j.boolField);
});
```

You can also add fail() to check for possible error. Check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: or even better, use a deferred http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Good point Tetaxa. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: can you post an answer using deferred? I had trouble with them.

Comment: Κωστας Ιωαννου: I edited my answer. You can also check the link provided by Tetaxa.